# Image size (324768098 pixels) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, fast-ai

Was facing an issue in classification model trained on fastai.

Running images in batches on a classification model. But due to 1 image, entire batch is failing. The classification model when trained was trained on preprocessed images, by applying transformations on image size = 224. When the particular image is passed through, it shows this error and entire batch fails.

#### "Image size (324768098) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack."

Why is this error showing then?

Had preprocessed the images when I trained the model, by providing image size to be 224.

I'd like to respect the limit and not increase the limit (as described here: Pillow in Python won't let me open image ("exceeds limit"))

How can I load it in a way that the resolution is lowered just below the limit and the lower resolution image is referenced in img without causing any error.

It'd be great to have a Python solution but if not, any other solution will work too.

Comment: basically running images in batches on a classification model. But due to 1 image, entire batch is failing. The classification model when trained was trained on preprocessed images, by applying transformations on image size = 224.

When the particular image is passed through, it shows this error and entire batch fails. I dont  want to bypass this security feature by PIL, but is there any other way that I can reduce the pixel/resolution of the image to process them?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have encountered a similar problem but don't mind fixing the code: find …/PIL/image.py and patch it:

```
$ diff -b -C 3 Image.py- Image.py
*** Image.py-   Sat Apr 15 16:11:17 2023
--- Image.py    Sat Apr 15 19:20:14 2023
***************
*** 91,97 ****
  
  
  # Limit to around a quarter gigabyte for a 24-bit (3 bpp) image
! MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = int(1024 * 1024 * 1024 // 4 // 3)
  
  
  try:
--- 91,97 ----
  
  
  # Limit to around a quarter gigabyte for a 24-bit (3 bpp) image
! MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = int(8192 * 8192 * 8192 // 4 // 3)
  
  
  try:
```